# jQuery .click() function only works once with $(window).load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been trying to make a list with a delete button to delete an element (using ajax).
When the element is deleted, I use `$("#tableId").load(window.load + " #tableId);` to update my table so the deleted element disappears, This works fine the first time, but when I delete an element for the first time and #tableId is loaded, I can't remove more items.

Here is the script:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
    $("#message").show();
    $("#message").html("Entro!");
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var tipo = href.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9])+/g, '');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/checkRemoverObjeto.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: 'tipo='+tipo+'&&id='+id,
        success: function(response){
            $("#message").show();
            $("#message").html(response);

            $("#tableId").load(window.location + " #tableId");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I searched but I could'nt find a solution.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation with `document` and [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){...});
```

This will attach the event handler to all current and future `.remove` elements

Comment: You should use `#tableId` instead of document. Has little performance gain

Comment: @Tushar, you are absolutely right. But I was afraid it would look like copying! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delegation using `on`. This will apply the events to the dynamically added elements inside the `#tableId`.

```
$("#tableId").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    // Your code here
});
```